# Replication Server version 15.7.1 - Sybase ASE 15.5 to Oracle EE 12.1.0.2 (64 bit) replication failing

Tags: oracle, replication, sybase

I have 2 Sybase DB and 1 Oracle DB, I would like to replicate one of the tables in Sybase DB X (table name: customer_order) into my Sybase DB Y (table name: customer_order), and from the Sybase DB Y replicate into Oracle. The replication linking is like this:-

Sybase DB X --> Sybase DB Y --> Oracle

The replication from Sybase DB X to Sybase DB Y is working fine, but replication failed from Sybase DB Y to Oracle. When I tried to insert/delete/update some records on Sybase DB Y, it has been replicated to Oracle, but...when I tried to insert/delete/update some records on Sybase DB X, these transactions are able to replicate to Sybase DB Y, but it couldn't replicate into Oracle. WHY??

Appreciate if anyone could solve my doubts. Thanks a lot.

FYI:-

- Replication Server version 15.7.1
- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
- Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 19395 SMP ESD#5/P/Sun_svr4/OS 5.8/asear155/2568/64-bit/FBO/Fri Dec 9 09:16:52 2011

Comment: How are you doing this replication (from Y (Sybase) -> Oracle)?

Comment: create replication definition repdef_ABC
with primary at testing.customers
with primary table named dbo.customer_order
with replicate table named PBO.'CUSTOMER_ORDER'
(
 customer_id             bigint,
        customer_name       varchar(500)                                                                                          
)
PRIMARY KEY (  customer_id )
go

create subscription sub_ABC for repdef_ABC
with replicate at <oracle connection in repserver>
without materialization
subscribe to truncate table
go

Comment: I'm doing the same thing like how I usually did the replication from Sybase ASE to Oracle, but it seems not working. I'm wondering whether it is because Replication Server does not support the linking? (Sybase DB X --> Sybase DB Y --> Oracle)

Comment: OK - two things: 1) put extra technical data in your question with a pointer back to it in comments (use @Vérace to let me know - i.e. @<+handle> in the comment) - that way, any new reader can see all of the relevant information without having to read through the comments and the person who asked for extra info knows you've put it in!

Comment: 2.)  Are you using [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/01/24/data-replication-architecture-for-integrating-heterogeneous-systems-with-oracle-databases/) product? It always helps (greatly) to include the name and version number of all products you are asking about. Take the site tour, read the [help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help) - also check this out! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: @Vérace Sorry about that.. I'm using Replication Server version 15.7.1 and Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production. To enable the replication work from Sybase ASE to Oracle, I did create Oracle connection in my replication server, Oracle connection defined with rs_ase_to_oracle;eco

Comment: And your Sybase version? I would, if I were you, edit your question to go something like "Replication Server version 15.7.1 - Sybase ASE <version...> to Oracle EE 12.1.0.2 (64 bit) replication failing!". Can you replicate from server X directly to Oracle?

Comment: @Vérace Sybase version: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 19395 SMP ESD#5/P/Sun_svr4/OS 5.8/asear155/2568/64-bit/FBO/Fri Dec  9 09:16:52 2011.  Yes, X can be replicated directly into Oracle, but due to user requirements, i'm requested to do the linking mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the repagent (in Sybase DB Y) will not replicate maintenance user transactions (ie, transactions replicated from Sybase DB X to Sybase DB Y).

To get the repagent (Sybase DB Y) to also replicate maintenance transactions (ie, transactions from Sybase DB X, once applied in Sybase DB Y, are then re-replicated to Oracle), you'll need to configure the Sybase DB Y repagent:

```
use <Sybase_DB_Y>
go
sp_config_rep_agent <Sybase_DB_Y>,'send maint xacts to replicate',true
go
sp_stop_rep_agent <Sybase_DB_Y>
go
-- wait for repagent to go down and then ...
sp_start_rep_agent <Sybase_DB_Y>
go
```